# Why is the gravity not working in Pymunk?

Tags: python, pygame, pymunk

I wanted to learn pymunk, but for some reason, the gravity isn't working. I watched many tutorials and even followed them word for word, but my gravity never works. This is the code I'm using for my main game, and I've sat here for hours thinking about what could've gone wrong but I still can't find it.

```
factory_items=[]
space=pymunk.Space()
space.gravity=(0,100)
```

```
class factory_item():
    def __init__(self):
        self.image=apple
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(100,100))
        self.body=pymunk.Body(1,100,body_type=pymunk.Body.DYNAMIC)
        self.body.pos=(random.randrange(0,401),0)
        self.shape=pymunk.Circle(self.body,50)
        space.add(self.body,self.shape)
    def update(self):
        win.blit(self.image,(self.body.pos[0]+scrollx,self.body.pos[1]))
```

The apples are being generated, but they aren't falling.

```
    if timer>0.5:
        timer=0
        var=factory_item()
        factory_items.append(var)

    for i in factory_items:
        i.update()

    space.step(1/50)
```

Comment: Where are is the code in which you are telling pymunk to update the position of your apples?

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you mean space.step(1/50)? I added that part but it still doesn't work. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrNpkuVIFdg&ab_channel=ClearCode

Comment: Actually, I copied tutorials exactly but it never works, so could you write something that works for you and then copy and paste it for me?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] so it's possible to assist you.

Comment: That's about as bare bones as it gets... there's nothing else that I can provide you to further clarify this problem. I think it's probably because of a bad download or something, because as I said I have copied tutorials word for word. My gravity just doesn't take affect. If you could give me some working code, nothing complex, maybe just a simple falling square, I could confirm whether it's my download or some other error. Thanks.

Comment: @mouse123 please review the [mcve] link to get a better idea of how you can help us to help you. I can't execute your code snippets nor identify the undesired operation you describe. Do you need to specify the mass of your shape? i.e. after creating `self.shape`, `self.shape.mass = 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong property to set/get positions of the bodies. The position property of a Pymunk Body is called `position`. You can see the full API documentation of the position (and everything else in Pymunk) here: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Body.position

So, try changing your code in the following way:

```py
self.body.pos=(random.randrange(0,401),0)
# should be 
self.body.position=(random.randrange(0,401),0)
# and 
win.blit(self.image,(self.body.pos[0]+scrollx,self.body.pos[1]))
# should be
win.blit(self.image,(self.body.position[0]+scrollx,self.body.position[1]))
```

If it still doesnt work you can try to post your full code (preferably something that we can run, but at the same time not too long) in your question, like import random wrote in the comments.

Comment: That's amazing, exactly what I needed. That'll teach me for slacking!